# How can I fit a curve of the type Y = aX^b using R?

Tags: r, model, regression, data-fitting, non-linear-regression

How can I fit a curve of the type $$Y = aX^b$$ using R?

I'm able to fit a linear model (Y = aX + b) using

```
fit <- lm(y~x)
```

but my data requires Y = aX^b

Comment: take the log of the the right side `ax^b` and fit a `lm`.

Comment: Use `nls` as in `nls(Y~a*X^b, start = list(a=0.001, b=0.5), data=your_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nls(y ~ a*x^b, start = list(a = 1, b = 1), data = your_data)`, or `lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = your_data)` (these are different models but either might serve you; the parameters of the second model are `log(a)` and `b`). You might need to adjust the starting values to work with your data.